# Using hash sign (#) as identifier/alias

Tags: javascript, jquery

The **$** sign is used by several libraries (jQuery, MooTools, Prototype).

Let say I have a Class called `ProjectServices` and wouldlike to create an alias like

```
var #PS = ProjectServices;
```

Wy is it not allowed to use **#** as alias or identifier in Javascript ?

Comment: because the spec says so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply not allowed by basic JavaScript syntax, while `$` is. Every programming language defines a syntax allowable for various kinds of symbols.

Comment: Letters, numbers, '$', and '_' are the only allowed characters.

Comment: @elimirks, [that's not quite right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/497418).

Answer (score 1):

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).
>   Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters
>   "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z"
>   (lowercase).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Comment: You left out the part that says "Starting with Javascript 1.5..."